# Remove lines that do not start with a pattern from a given set of patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, awk

I have a file that contains data like this:

```
report aaaaaaaa  
-  ..  
-th bbbbbbbbb  
-to ccccccccc

.. --.
```

Question: I want to remove any line that does not start with following strings :

```
report  
-th  
-to
```

that means the desire output will remove all those middle unwanted dots and hashes and will look like this :

```
report aaaaaaaa  
-th bbbbbbbbb  
-to ccccccccc
```

`sed`/`awk`/`grep`/etc any solution that will work.

Answer (score 19):

Using `sed` to modify the file in place:

```
sed -i '/^\(report\|-t\(h\|o\)\)/!d' your_file
```

This instructs `sed` to delete all lines not matching the pattern. The pattern itself is `^` (start of line), followed by either `report` or `-t` followed by either `h` or `o`.

You should note that this is not actual in-place modification: `sed` creates a temporary backup copy and overwrites the original file with it.

If you want `sed` to keep a backup copy of the original file (which might be a good idea if the file contains critical data), give the `-i` switch an extension to create a backup file:

```
sed -i'.bak' -e '/^\(report\|-t\(h\|o\)\)/!d' your_file
```

will modify `your_file` and create a backup of the original called `your_file.bak`.

**A side note**

Please don't misconstrue my intentions or take offence at this, but I've noticed that you have many similar regex/text-processing related questions. I advise you to start learning `sed`, `awk` and `grep` on your own to help speed up your productivity. Again, don't get me wrong, I'm all too happy to help (as are most people around here); it's just that I think that you stand to benefit hugely from picking up these tools for your daily use.

Just to prove how helpful people are around here, consider @slm's suggestion in the comments below and feel free to drop by [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) any time for questions.

Comment: Your regular expression seems unnecessarily cryptic. I think you actually use more characters than if you had just listed the three options explicitly.

Comment: @nispio I know, but it's likely to be more efficient if the file in question is large.

Comment: Interesting.  I have always measured regexps in terms of length or readability.  I have never given much thought to execution speed. I don't think I know enough about how they are evaluated to judge what is fast, but I assume that it is implementation specific too, right?

Comment: Re-iterating what Joseph said about being willing to help, if you have general questions that don't fit in the Q&A style you can always try chatting us up in the chat room for this site. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux. Several of us live in there 8-)

Comment: @slm Thank you for this. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @nispio To gain in efficiency, it's usually recommended to factor out any constant components in alternation because regex engines can optimize the matching around them. In this particular case, however, I ran some tests and neither pattern style seems to have a distinct performance advantage.

Comment: @nispio It is indeed implementation-specific. Regex engines that favor "longest leftmost match" tend to benefit from well-written alternations. OTOH, engines that favor "longest overall match" always go through all branches of  an alternation. If you work a lot with regex, I can't recommend [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922570.do) enough.

Answer (score 11):

You can use simple grep for this:

```bash
grep -E '^(report|-th|-to)' filename
```

or, shorter,

```bash
grep -E '^(report|-t[ho])' filename
```

Comment: It's not much of a savings, but you could combine the `-th`/`-to` into `-t[ho]`.

Comment: You're missing `-v` to negate this regex. This filter for lines that *do* start with those strings.

Comment: @thisismydesign and that is exactly what is requested (the double negation in the question doesn’t help).

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^report|^-t[ho]/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^report\|^-th\|^-to/p' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^report|^-t[ho]/' filename > newfile
```

or, to edit in place (like `sed`, `perl` will also make a temporary backup so this is not true *in place* editing):

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if /^report|^-t[ho]/' filename
```

That will make a copy of the original file called `filename.bak` and overwrite your original file with the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

The questioner has made two points:

- wanting to remove any line not starting with "report" or "-th" or "-to".
- the desired output should remove "all those middle unwanted dots and hashes (sic)"

The solutions, at this time, address the first point and thereby also the second. But suppose the the file is larger and looks like:

```
report aaaaaaaa  
-  ..  
-th bbbbbbbbb  
-to ccccccccc
anything else
.. --.
-tp ddd
-tq eee
     -  -----
```

Wouldn't addressing OP's second point do the needful?

```
sed -r -i.bak '/^[ |.|-]*$/d' input-file
```

does the job of removing presumably unwanted lines containing just spaces, dots and dashes and retaining the rest, whatever that is.
I would think that the risk of either approach is that the nature of the file isn't properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if m/^ [ report | \-th | \-to ] /;' file.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
report aaaaaaaa  
-  ..  
-th bbbbbbbbb  
-to ccccccccc

.. --.
```

Sample Output:

```
report aaaaaaaa  
-th bbbbbbbbb  
-to ccccccccc
```

This is a similar answer to the Perl answer posted by @terdon. Raku's `-ne` command line flags autochomps the linewise input, but using `put` prints with an EOL terminator (remember `put` in Raku as an acronym for *print-using-terminator*). The call `.put` is short for `$_.put`, which outputs the `$_` topic variable (i.e. the input line).

Otherwise, grouping regex atoms in Raku is accomplished by square brackets, and any non-`alnum` character must be escaped to be understood literally (otherwise Raku presumes it to have special Regex meaning, like `.` dot).

https://raku.org